# Building a string recursively in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to build a string recursively but it isn't quite working

my code looks like this

```
    public void UpdatePrintList(ArrayList<Node> closedList, ArrayList<Node> openList)
    {
        if(count <= iterations)
        {
            String line1 = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < closedList.size(); i++)
            {
                if(i > 0)
                {
                    line1 = line1 + "-";
                }
                line1 = line1 + closedList.get(i).GetMovement();
            }

            line1 = line1 + " " + closedList.get(closedList.size()-1).GetG() + " " + closedList.get(closedList.size()-1).GetHeuristic() + " " + closedList.get(closedList.size()-1).GetF();
            printList.add(line1);            
            //*****************************************************************                
String line2 = "OPEN ";

        for(int i = 0; i < openList.size(); i++)
        {
            line2 = FindEarlierNode(openList.get(i), line2);
        }
        System.out.println(line2);
    }
    count++;
}

private String FindEarlierNode(Node varNode, String varString)
{
    if(varNode.OpenedBy() == null)
    {
        varString += varNode.GetMovement() + "-";
    }
    else
    {
        FindEarlierNode(varNode.OpenedBy(), varString);
    }
    varString = varString + varNode.GetMovement() + "-";
    return varString;
}
```

The strange thing is that I know that this if statement

```
        if(varNode.OpenedBy() == null)
    {
        varString += varNode.GetMovement() + "-";
    }
```

runs correctly, so the function does reach the earliest node. But it doesnt add to the string. The code runs but returns nothing. GetMovement just returns a one or two character string. The output should look like this:

OPEN S-R S-RD S-D

But instead it looks like this:

OPEN D-DL-L-

Can anyone help?

Comment: The top portion of your code appears to be cut off, so I'm afraid we cannot help much until you fix your question.

Comment: Don't use upper case in a method name, instead of FindEarlierNode use findEarlierNode

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out. This gives me my desired output:

```
    private String FindEarlierNode(Node varNode, String varString)
{
    if(varNode.OpenedBy() != null)
    {
        varString = varString + varNode.GetMovement() + "-";
        return FindEarlierNode(varNode.OpenedBy(), varString);

    }

    return varString += varNode.GetMovement() + " ";
}
```

thanks everyone.